# Is there a way to conditional format (only 2 colors) filtered rows based on Cell Value change?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I have 2 columns where I have used this custom formula -

```
=ISEVEN(SUMPRODUCT((A$1:A1<>A$2:A2)))
```

to conditionally format rows based on values in column A.

[image: The image shows the rows being highlighted when the cell value changes.]

This formula works fine, but when I try to filter rows, the formula breaks and does not adapt to the new rows. Is there a way where I can use a formula which can be used for visible cells?

[The formula breaks when I try to filter the rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BegTI.png)

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve with your conditional formatting? I have tried implementing yours obtaining different results. Is your intention to alternate the formatting grouping the same text in ```A``` together?

Answer (score 0):

put this in C2 and drag down (when done you can hide this column):

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, A2)
```

and use custom formula in conditional formatting:

```
=ISODD(MATCH($A2, UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A, $C$2:$C=1)), 0))
```

[image]